# How Would I create alternate players (Turn base Event)

Tags: unity, turn-based

[image]

The picture above shows 2 players.  Each containing 3 characters.  I want to know how to make a Turn based event starting with player 1 alternating turns with player 2.  And in every alternation each character gets a turn.  If a character dies, the next character on the same team goes, and so on.

How would I create this?  Is there a tutorial?  I haven't made any turn-based games so I don't know how to program these kinds of stuff.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to implement turn-based game engine?](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/8239/how-to-implement-turn-based-game-engine)

Comment: It's far from being a duplicate of that. Linked question is about a general problem, answered with code structure of a whole game, while this is a specific problem having specific solutions.

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady I initially disagreed, but saw the specifics reflected in your answer. And based on your answer, this might be a better fit for SO, since it's fundamentally about nested loops.

Comment: Hi @michael.bartnett , this is not a question about nested loops, it would be, if Blue wanted to place a statement in lower level of nested loop, to skip to next step in higher iteration, or had some similar problem. This question is about a gameplay mechanic solution, it could be even denied on SO as too general, without any example code not working. And please notice this: http://area51.stackexchange.com/faq "_When voting, focus on your site_
Don't worry about whether a question might be asked on another site. Your goal is to make the best possible site for this community."

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady Although Blue is not asking about nested loops and has dressed it up in a turn-based game scenario, that's what the fundmental concept is: Foreach character in foreach player's group of characters. It felt out of place on the site to me because it is so general and only nominally related to gamedev. The other question covered approaches to handling player turns more thoroughly, so that's why I suggested the duplicate.

Comment: @michael.bartnett Well, you're right, looking at my own answer the problem seems quite simple.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have 2 players always, you'll then need, for each player:

- A list containing their characters
- A counter for which of their characters is currently active

As the players trade turns their character counter should go up until it hits it's maximum size (3?) and then start back over at 1. Should a character die, take appropriate action to keep the counter correct. This is something your overall game needs to keep track of, only changing after a turn has been completed.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know Unity, so treat this as a pseudo-code:

```
var charList:Array = new Array ();

var continueLoop:Boolean = true;
for ( var i:int = 0; continueLoop; i++ ) {
   continueLoop = false;
   for each ( var p:Player in players ) {
      if ( p.units.length > i ) {
         charList.push ( p.units[i] );
         continueLoop = true;
      }
   }
}
```

Now divide the turn to `charList.length` number of rounds, and activate the `charList[current_round]` unit on beginning of every round. Sort player.units by unit speed, if you want to give them initiative in *Heroes of Might and Magic III* style.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply queue the players in order and just dequeue the first in line. The trigger to add them to the queue totally depends on your system ( I think a state machine could be in order here ). For example; if your character order depend on various triggers like stats and timers. You should monitor their properties and add them to the queue if a certain conditions are met.

I can't really give you any specific code or an example because it's specific to your system obviously. Look up how queues work if you don't know them yet.